# Unsubscribed User's IM Status in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, xmpp, google-talk

I am implementing an GAE application where I need to show the chat status of any user using user's gmail address that belongs to a certain domain.

The user has no idea of the application and the application has not being added to the user's contact/IM list.

Is it possible?

Comment: Don't you think this would be a bit of a violation of users' privacy if this were achievable?

Comment: Edited my question. The application will run in the confines of a certain domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible. XMPP only exposes status messages for contacts that have accepted a subscribe request.

Comment: Is there any other way that the purpose can be achieved? Anything in Contacts API or Domain APIs that can get me the status of the users in a Business domain? Any feed that I can use?

Comment: No; the contract for status messages is that they're only exposed to your subscribed contacts.

Comment: Hit the wall then! Thanks Moishe